# Failed to deploy Java Spring-boot to GCP App Engine

Tags: hibernate, maven, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am getting errors while deploying to App Engine.
I run this command

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests appengine:deploy -e -Pcloud-gcp
```

as shown on the pom.xml file, there is a profile caled cloud-gcp, because that we have -Pcloud-gcp in the command line
and -DskipTests to skip tests

this command is run in the app engine ssh (cloud shell)

The question is, how to solve this deployment error, and how to deploy this app?

## pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.hatim.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>hatim</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.23.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger Dependencies for documintation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
        <id>cloud-gcp</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>verify</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

## src/main/appengine/app.yaml

```
runtime: java
env: flex
runtime_config:
  jdk: openjdk8
env_variables:
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: "gcp,mysql"
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 2
  disk_size_gb: 10

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: rmit-events:us-central1:events=tcp:3306
```

### resources/application.properties

```xml
#Do not edit anything from here
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

spring.jpa.open-in-view=true

# Initialize the datasource with available DDL and DML scripts
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

# mysql db connection url
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://google/events?cloudSqlInstance=rmit-events:us-central1:events&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory


# db username
spring.datasource.data-username=some-user

# db password
spring.datasource.data-password=some-password

# server port
server.port=8080

spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=rmit-events:us-central1:events
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=events
```

## Log

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yytW-VYnd-1BHCX9bq2T59YmbJc64pFm/view?usp=sharing

## UPDATE

when I run package without deployment

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests -e -Pcloud-gcp
```

i get BUILD SUCCESS

Comment: Is it work locally?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes, it works locally on local mysql db

Comment: And an appengine:run also work? So try to add this [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-core/0.8.0) as workaround, but it's dirty.

Comment: I noticed in your pom.xml that you are using version 1.3.2 of the app engine plugin, per this doc[1] the current version is 2.1.0, Could you please try with the latest version? The error shown describes a methodNotFound Error so this could be related.

[1] https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.tools/appengine-maven-plugin